# Mac - KeyRemap4MacBook - Custom XML

Tags: mac, xml

I hope someone of you know this powerfull Pref Panel to remap the keyboard..

Since i'm using a PC Keyboard, i wanted to make Screenshot a bit easy to do..

I managed to get working:

-Command+Shift+3 to Stamp (full screen screenshot)

-Command+Shift+4 to Control+Stamp (Selection Cursor Screenshot)

Now i want to remap Shift+Stamp to Command+Shift+4+Space to get Windows Screenshot.. i tried but nothing was working..

Here is my current XML.. i only need to add the last remap!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>Custom PC Style Screenshot</name>
<appendix>Command+Shift_L+4+Space to Shift+F13</appendix>
<appendix>Command+Shift_L+4 to Control+F13</appendix>
<appendix>Command+Shift_L+3 to F13</appendix>
<identifier>private.custom_pc_style_screenshot</identifier>
<autogen></autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F13, VK_CONTROL, KeyCode::KEY_4, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F13, KeyCode::KEY_3, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
```

Hope someone of you can help me out! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work after adding a small delay:

`<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F13, VK_SHIFT, KeyCode::KEY_4, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_WAIT_10MS, KeyCode::SPACE</autogen>`